# BottomNavigationView, onFocusChange of TextView on previous fragment is called only after onResume on new fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, textview, bottomnavigationview

I'm working on an Android app with a `NavController` and `BottomNavigationView` and Fragments for each of the tabs. On the first few tabs (fragments) the user can enter several values, and then on the final right-most tab a result is displayed based on these values.

The underlying values are updated in the `onFocusChange()` of the TextViews, and a calculation result on the last Fragment is refreshed in the `onResume()` of that fragment.

This all works fine, except for one situation; When the user changes a value, then leaves the cursor in that TextView and then taps on the `BottomNavigationView` to switch over to the last Fragment, now the `onFocusChange` is called only AFTER the `onResume()` on the new fragment is called. I've made an illustration below:

[image]

In other words, `onResume()` is called before `onFocusChage()`, so the calculation display is refreshed before the value is updated, so it looks like the calculation is not updated. When you then switch tabs again, for example from (3) to (2) and then back to (3), then it does show the correct new calculated value.

I've been wrecking my head on this for hours because this is quite ugly GUI behaviour.
Is there any way to fix this? And if so how?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not computing the value every time the text changes and only when the text field loses focus?

Comment: The reason it's only computed when a text field loses focus is because each value is also checked for min/max values. For example, when you enter temperature 999, the internal value is capped at 50 C (or max 122 for F) and then the TextView is also updated in the `onFocusChange`. If you do this every time a digit is typed, the text will change in the middle of typing which is jarring and annoying to the user.

Comment: Btw the TextViews update each separate interval value, the calculations are only computed in the `onResume()`. And the older app version used a `TabView` element and there this setup worked fine, but with the BottomNavController and Fragments this occurs as a side-effect.

Comment: Wow this is quite a hard problem to fix. Using `TextWatcher` is also not practical because `afterTextChanged` is also triggered too late, and `onTextChanged` doesn't have a Editble as paramter, which means I'd have to add separate `TextWatcher` for all my `TextViews` and implement them all separately which is quite a lot. Just to fix this one tiny thing? Am I missing something here?